# Sharing one MenuStrip between multiple Forms and "open, save, save as" each form separately

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm able with 1 MenuStrip to show multiple Forms in a panel "PanelSlider_Utils" like this :

```
public Utils()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Job1());
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Job2());
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Job3());
}
```

and call the function

```
private void DefinirJob1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Find("Job1", false)[0].BringToFront();
}

private void DefinirJob2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Find("Job2", false)[0].BringToFront();
}

private void DefinirJob3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Find("Job3", false)[0].BringToFront();
}
```

How can I open, save, save as file for each form with the same MenuStrip?

I have been trying and searching for 2 days ... Please Help !

Comment: That depends, what do you want to open/save/save as? What I mean is, do you need each form to have its own logic for those commands or just one central piece of code that you can reuse based on the form triggering the event?

Comment: I need each form to have it's own logic for those commands. Thanks Camilo

Comment: Maybe the second option would be as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok no problem

I've a Main form and call multiple panel (PanelSlider) with 1 MenuStrip with UserControl :

```
        public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Home());
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Tools());
        etc...
    }
```

Active Panel with button

```
    private void HomeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelSlider.Controls.Find("Home", false)[0].BringToFront();

    }
```

So to switch the multiple panel I declared a menustrip and for example:

```
    private void CallToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Find("Tools", false)[0].BringToFront();
    }
```

The problem was for 1 menustrip to open/save/save as option

The solution:

```
public void SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tools obj = this.Controls.Find("TOOLS", true)[0] as Tools;
    if (Tools != null)
        Tools.new_method();
}
```

and call new_method like this in TOOLS Form:

```
public void new_method()
{
 ...my code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for UserControl is:

```
public void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foo obj = this.Controls.Find("MYFORM", true)[0] as foo;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.new_method();
}
```

and I call new_method like this in MYFORM:

```
public void new_method()
{
 ...my code...
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.